# Curl command appending local system drive path

Tags: curl, git-bash, consul-kv

I am trying to update the value for a key in Consul (Consul key/value pairs) with help of curl command.

Here key is `School/Class/ClassName` and value is `/School/class/Seventh`

The command is:

```
curl -XPUT -d "/School/class/Seventh" "http://consulserverurl/School/Class/ClassName"
```

I am executing above command from 'Git Bash'

When I ran this command, the 'value' in consul is updated to `C:/USers/myuserid/appData/Local/Programs/Git/School/class/Seventh` rather than updating it to `/School/class/Seventh`

How to avoid appending my local system path to the actual value?

I need forward slash "/" before "School/class/Seventh".